# Location and folder name of wp-bakery

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wanted to to move and start my wordpress site localy.

I can't recognize wp-bakery folder and actually I don't know is the folder of plugin in plugin folder or inside the theme (I have truemag theme)

Best Regards,

Daryush

Answer (score 14, accepted):

WPBakery Page Builder plugin directory is: wp-content/plugins/js_composer

Answer (score 2):

The normal location for plugins are wp-content/plugins. I guess you can find your plugin files in wp-content/plugins/pluginname

Comment: The name of the plugin is "WPBakery Page Builder" however the plugin folder name is "js_composer". So unlike most plugins the plugin name and plugin folder name are different in this case. Most likely due to the name of the plugin having been recently changed.

Comment: The question "Location and folder name of wp-bakery" has the meaning that someone can't find the WP Bakery plugin folder. The are many plugins with different name folder

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the primary folder is named something completely illogical: "js_composer".

A little nice to know: most of the time, people also use the "Ultimate Addons for WPBakery Page Builder" plugin, and that is also pretty well hidden. The folder is named "Ultimate_VC_Addons".

Enjoy Bakery. It's phenomenal for creating and moving contents on a page.